# Word usage: feeble

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Is it correct to say

> Feeble people are more at risk of flu-related complications.

to convey the idea that there are different levels of risk in the population at risk? I could have said *old people* instead of *feeble people*, but I would like to stay vague at this point. Is *weak* a better alternative for *feeble*?

Comment: How about 'some people' (or 'certain people')?

Comment: @GlenTheUdderboat: It might work, indeed. I would like to convey the idea of weakness, though.

Comment: "Most infected people recover within one to two weeks without requiring medical treatment. However, in the very young, the elderly, and those with other serious medical conditions, infection can lead to severe complications of the underlying condition, pneumonia and death." This is the wording chosen [here](http://www.who.int/topics/influenza/en/). I don't think there is a term for the combination of those at-risk groups (other than 'at-risk groups').

Comment: It sounds a bit tautologous; one could just as well say that people who are more at risk of flu-related complications are feeble. It hasn't really told me anything about what sort of people are at risk, unlike say "elderly, very young, and infirm people".

Comment: I was going to answer with "high-risk category" knowing full well that it isn't a single word until I saw *frail*. Someone in frail health is unambiguous.

Comment: Immunodeficient cuts closer to your intended purpose than any of the answers sited below. It's interesting to see that the only person who mentioned immunodeficiency is downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both convey the idea that one is lacking the power to perform a physically demanding task or lacking physical strength and energy. However *feeble* leans towards lacking the power/energy... *as a result of age or illness*.

*Feeble* is, as you said, more vague than directly saying *old people*, but still sends out the wanted message that people of older age are more at risk of flu-related complications.

Both could be used. But in this situation, as WS2 pointed out, you might want to use *elderly* as you seem to be implying that people of old-age are more at risk. But it wont necessarily mean that they are weak.

If you *really* need to convey the message of weakness, *feeble* would be the way to go.

Answer (score 15):

**Frail** is a preferred adjective in the private health-care sector in the UK, from personal experience of working in that industry.

Feeble is regarded more as unfit for it's negative connotations of mental weakness, where such words as **emotionally or mentally (or even cognitively) vulnerable** are deemed apt.

Comment: tank you, i like your suggestion.

Comment: This is the most appropriate word in this context because  feeble is open to multiple misinterpretations.

Comment: I wouldn't however say, "frail people" but opt for *"people in frail health"*

Comment: @Mari-LouA I disagree. I wouldn't necessarily consider a (relatively) healthy 75 year old someone 'in frail health'. However, I would consider them (absolutely) 'frail'.

Comment: Glad you agree with me! :) Someone in "frail health" can be at any age. If a 75 year-old man/woman is fit, healthy  and strong I would never consider them to be frail by virtue of their age. It is true that with advanced age, one's health generally falters; but I live in a part of Italy where many an 80-year-old is still very active.

Comment: @Mari-LouA No, I don't agree. :) Apparently, the specified risk-factor at issue is age, not activeness. Objectively 'frail' would seem to apply (for all elderly), but 'frail health' doesn't necessarily (depending on your definition of health).

Comment: Advanced age is certainly a risk factor but it's not an absolute that a 70-75 year-old will suffer from complications. If that person is *fit*, a non-smoker, does not suffer from diabetes, high blood pressure, obesity etc. he or she may well be healthier than a 40-year-old.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sure, but that's really beside the point. (Those are typically considered _other_ factors.) _Unless_ you _also_ consider the very young to be 'in frail health' rather than just 'frail'. Do you?

Answer (score 2):

I think this boils down to what exactly you mean by 'feeble'. The primary meaning in Collins Dictionary is 'lacking in physical and mental strength'.

Now, just because someone lacks 'strength' (i.e. they are not muscular and able to lift heavy weights), does not, I would suggest, render them any more at risk of flu-related complications than anyone else.

I am not a medical person, so please don't place any reliance medically on this, but it could be that if the feebleness is caused by some other chronic condition such as diabetes, or is the result of old-age, then it may well make them more liable to flu-related conditions. Everyone over the age of 60 in Britain is entitled to a free anti-flu vaccination once per year, and is encouraged to have it. So it does seem that older people are at risk. But I know plenty over 60 who are certainly not 'feeble'.

So I would tend to rephrase the sentence as;

'Elderly or infirm people are at more risk of flu-related complications.'

'Weak' has exactly the same problems as 'feeble'.

Comment: I doubt 'infirm' covers the group at risk (other than the 'elderly'). 'Infirm', to me, means _already_ stricken (with/by something).

Comment: @GlenTheUdderboat Well, if they are not old and not 'already stricken with something' I don't see why they should be at more risk than anyone else.

Comment: @WS2 '[T]he very young' are one such category.

Comment: @GlenTheUdderboat Yes, you are quite right. Apparently the very young are particularly at risk of pneumonia as a complication of flu. (I should have known because I believe it happened to me as a child - but that was in 1945) So perhaps we need to change the sentence to read: 'The very young, the elderly and the infirm....'

Comment: @WS2 I already commented to the question that the WHO uses (for infections) "the very young, the elderly, and those with other [than influenza] serious medical conditions". :)

Comment: @WS2 Also, I wouldn't consider somebody having high blood pressure, but not aware of it or suffering from any of its effects, 'infirm'.

Comment: @GlenTheUdderboat So how exactly would you word the sentence?

Comment: @GlenTheUdderboat So what we are talking about is 'infirm' versus 'other serious medical conditions'. Sounds as if  we are splitting hairs. And if the blood-pressure sufferer is not aware that he/she has it, then 'serious medical condition' wouldn't cover them either. Perhaps we should say 'Any person may at any time find themselves at higher than usual risk of flu complications'!

Comment: @WS2 Good question. Assuming established medical knowledge (I'm not knowledgeable), either 'the very young, the elderly, and those with other serious medical conditions', or 'the frail' for short. :) (Your latest comment is plain wrong. Even if you're not aware of your high blood pressure, it may still be a serious medical condition.) But I agree that a tautology is (always) best.

Answer (score 1):

People with low immunity ....  works good I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this sentence sounds more neutral:

People of advanced age, who are in fragile health, are more at risk of flu-related complications.

"Old" and "feeble" may have negative connotations.